# Знаки вопроса при запросе через Mysql на страницу php

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

MySQL отправляет знаки вопроса вместо русских символов. Я уже везде где можно установил кодировку utf-8, везде уже писал SET NAMES utf-8 и htaccess создавал и AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 туда писал.

Создавал базу данных с нуля в кодировке UTF-8, Mysql все равно отправляет мне знаки вопроса, хотя сами русские символы в php коде работают. Что может быть не так?

[image: вот]

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';` все кроме `..filesystem | ...dir` должно быть utf8

Answer (score 0):

При создании таблицы необходимо указывать им  кодировку по умолчанию, чтоб не зависеть от настроек хостера:

```
create table (
...
) default charset utf8
```

Изменить уже созданным таблицам можно через ALTER TABLE

```
alter table tablename CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Comment: я все это делал, проблема в ajax запросах. Он мне знаки вопроса отправляет. У всех такая проблема. Либо переходить на латиницу навсегда, либо вообще не использовать ajax